# Attach TargetWithoutContext to an AppBarButton

Tags: windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

I have a `Conductor<MyItem>.Collection.OneActive` ViewModel and try to attach the application bar buttons to methods of `MyItem` with `cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{ Binding ActiveItem }"`. My view is a Pivot, if someone wonders why am I trying to attach the application bar to a child ViewModel. The compiler says *"Property 'TargetWithoutContext' is not attachable to elements of type 'AppBarButton'."* Though it works with normal buttons elsewhere in the view.

How can I get it work? Or maybe any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppBar functionality that Caliburn.Micro provides is a hack due to the flaws in the underlying framework, which doesn't allow arbitrary binding. Unfortunately, we can't support TargetWithoutContext. For AppBars the target will always be the page's view model and messages can only be directed to it. If the page's view model is a conductor, and you want a child to receive the message, you could have the conductor receive it and then forward it on to its ActiveItem.

Comment: Yes, I already do this. It isn't DRY, but I can live with it. The main problem is how do I use the guard method "CanDoThings" from the child model?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly the ApplicationBar is not bindalbe as it is not Part of the Silverlight Framework.
You can only interact with the Application via the Code Behind File of the Page which uses the ApplicationBar.

You have to register the Click Event and invoke the Action form the code Behind.

Comment: Can you extend your answer with a code example? How do I invoke the correct CM action from the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

The WP7 ApplicationBar is just a simple wrapper around the native shell and doesn't support data binding at all. However, there are a couple of workarounds available. 
http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/232742

Comment: I already use the CM's AppBarButton. The question was how to forward the action to a child view model.